# Error opening input stream for resource module-info.class

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, tomcat7, web-deployment

I'm seeing this recently when I deploy my application on WebSphere.

```
  W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource module-info.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/stax-ex-1.8.jar
                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.getScannedClasses(ScannerContextImpl.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses(WebAppImpl.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5487)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5613)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

When I deploy the same WAR on Tomcat, it works. I'm using JDK 1.7.80.
Has anyone else seen this ? If so what's the fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `module-info` file was newly introduced in Java 9. Bytecode scanning libraries (such as ASM) need to be updated in order to understand the new `module-info` class file, otherwise they will hit this exception. Since you are running on Java 7, the `module-info.class` file has no effect (aside from causing ASM to blow up).

Your options appear to be:

1. Update ASM to a version that supports Java 9, which is ASM 6.0 or newer
2. Do not package libraries that contain `module-info.class`, such as `stax-ex-1.8.jar`, in your application.
3. Remove `module-info.class` files from libraries, such as `stax-ex-1.8.jar`, so that bytecode scanning tools like ASM do not blow up when they see them.

Comment: @GonzaloPrendes do you used maven? How to exclude this class using maven?